# Using pandas nullable integer dtype in np.where condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean, missing-data

I have a DataFrame below which has some missing values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['A', 1, None], ['B', 2, 5]],
                  columns=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
```

Since `df['Z']` is supposed to be an integer column, I changed its data type to `pandas` new experimental type [nullable integer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values) as below.

```
ydf['Z'] = ydf['Z'].astype(pd.Int32Dtype())
ydf

    X   Y   Z
0   A   1   <NA>
1   B   2   5
```

Now I am trying to use a simple `numpy` where method to replace the non-null values in the column `df['Z']` with a fixed integer value (say `1`) using the code below.

```
np.where(pd.isna(ydf['Z']), pd.NA, np.where(ydf['Z'] > 0, 1, 0))
```

But I get the following error, and I am unable to understand why as I am already checking for the rows with null values in the first condition.

```
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

Comment: `np.where(ydf['Z'] > 0, 1, 0)` is throwing the error.

Comment: Yes I know that but why?

Comment: I think `np.where` expected an array of booleans only, but `ydf['Z'] > 0` returns nans like `<NA>`

Comment: Yeah, and `df['Z'] > 0` (where `df` is the original df, before converting it to the new Int32 type) returns `False` for nan.

Comment: Understood. That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` expects an array of booleans. With the `int64` dtype, using `>` on the Series returns `False` for nans. With the `Int32` dtype (note the capital `I`), `>` doesn't coerce nans to False, thus the error.

One solution would be to use `ydf['Z'].gt(0).fillna(False)` instead of `ydf['Z'] > 0`. (They're the same, the second one just changes NA to False):

```
np.where(pd.isna(ydf['Z']), pd.NA, np.where(ydf['Z'].gt(0).fillna(False), 1, 0))
```

Comment: Quick question. Shouldn't the second `np.where` condition consider only the rows that are rejected as `False` in the first condition where I am checking for `NA`. Otherwise what is the point of a **nested** condition.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @user17242583, `np.where` need an array of boolean values only but your comparison return a tri-state array: `True`, `False` and `<NA>`.

```
>>> df['Z'] > 0
0    <NA>
1    True
Name: Z, dtype: boolean
```

In this case, `np.where` can't decide if the returned value should be interpreted as `True` or `False`.

Just cast on the fly your column:

```
>>> np.where(pd.isna(df['Z']), pd.NA, np.where(df['Z'].astype(float) > 0, 1, 0))

array([<NA>, 1], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option, that could be helpful here is the [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when.case_when) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), that could help with the nested expressions, and also works with Pandas extension array types:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.case_when(
      df.Z.isna(), df.Z, # condition, result
      df.Z.gt(0), 1,
      0, # default value if False
      column_name='Z')

   X  Y     Z
0  A  1  <NA>
1  B  2     1
```